# Is there a native HTML parsing module for Python 3.2?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

I am trying to parse some html. I would like something like `sgmllib` but it is deprecated in python 3.2.

Is there an alternate module that I can use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Built-in HTMLParser module:
http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/html.parser.html

Not native but worth to mention;
BeautifulSoup:
http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Comment: +1 for Beautiful Soup, because real-world HTML is a friggin' mess. BS just rolls with whatever crap you throw at it and comes up smiling.

Comment: @Peter: Unfortunately, BeautifulSoup doesn't work so well with Python 3, as it depends on sgmllib. I fiddled around with making it work with the newer html5lib, but it's not complete. https://code.launchpad.net/~takowl/beautifulsoup/3k http://code.google.com/r/takowl-html5lib/ (Feel free to work on it if you're interested).

Comment: Perfect. I think I will use HTMLParser since it is very similar to `sgmllib`. I also read a lot about `BeautifulSoup` and people are complaining about compatibility issues with Python 3. Thanks.

Comment: on that page it says Python 3.1 has problems, but fixed in 3.2:
http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/3.1-problems.html

Comment: @utdmr: Unfortunate co-incidence - those are the version numbers of BeautifulSoup itself. BS 3.2 is not compatible with Python 3.x. Only BS 3.1, the version with problems, runs on Python 3.x.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what you mean by native, but I'm a big fan of [lxml](http://lxml.de/).

Comment: +1 I second ilprincipe that lxml is better: more flexible and faster. Especially when used with Twisted.